# Crash issue related to CTRun and CTRunGetPositions

Tags: ios, core-text

I encountered a peculiar issue. In a project from many years ago, there is a piece of code like this:

```
func testFunc() {
 // ......
 let runs = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(finalLine) as! [CTRun]
 if let truncationRun = runs.last {
     var truncationPosition = CGPoint.zero
     CTRunGetPositions(truncationRun, CFRange(location: 0, length: 0), &truncationPosition)
     var truncationAscent: CGFloat = 0, truncationDescent: CGFloat = 0
     let truncationWidth = CTRunGetTypographicBounds(truncationRun, CFRange(location: 0, length: 0), &truncationAscent, &truncationDescent, nil)
     // ......
 }
 // ......
```

}

When the number of glyphs in truncationRun exceeds a certain value, a crash occurs after the function execution ends. This value varies across different iOS systems – on iOS 13, it is 11; on iOS 15, it is 7; and on iOS 17, it is 8. I do not understand why this happens?

[image]

Of course, if space for the trancationPosition control is allocated based on the CTRunGetGlyphCount() method, this code runs normally.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is "why **doesn't** this crash when the run is short?" This code should definitely crash in the general case since it tries to write an array of CGPoints into space allocated for a single CGPoint. This corrupts other memory and crashes. Classic buffer overflow.

But as to why in some cases it doesn't crash, it depends heavily on what comes immediately after `truncationPosition` in memory. The memory you corrupt may not have anything in it. It may have something in it that doesn't "matter." It may be empty due to alignment requirements. The larger the overflow, the more likely you'll run into something important or smash the stack itself.

But the short answer is that writing beyond your buffer is undefined behavior, and the system does not promise it will crash. Often it will, but often it may just do strange things or even "work." What happens can change between OS versions, and even between runs of the same code on the same version.

Comment: My apologies, it seems that I may not have been clear in my explanation. The current phenomenon is that this piece of code will inevitably crash when the number of glyphs in truncationRun exceeds a certain value. My question is: why does this "specific value" vary across different iOS systems? As you mentioned, I  understand that it should definitely trigger a buffer overflow as long as the number of glyphs in truncationRun exceeds more than 1 since the code only allocates memory space for a single CGPoint. So, why is this "specific value" 11 on iOS 13, 7 on iOS 15, and 8 on iOS 17?

Comment: I discovered another piece of information yesterday: this issue occurs only in the Release Build Configuration; it does not happen in a Debug Build Configuration.

Comment: "I understand that it should definitely trigger a buffer overflow as long as the number of glyphs in truncationRun exceeds more than 1 since the code only allocates memory space for a single CGPoint." Yes, it will **cause** an overflow. Whether that overflow leads to a crash is completely dependent on the precise setup of...well...everything. There is no promise whatsoever that writing outside your buffer will crash the program. It is the ultimate in undefined behavior. It is not some specific amount of allowance for each version.

Comment: Release mode greatly changes things as well, including (often most importantly) much more aggressive deallocating of memory than Debug builds. This often leads to Release builds crashing in cases that Debug builds do not. The fact that it doesn't crash does not mean the operation is valid; only that it did not crash. If you want to explore the details of exactly why it occurs or doesn't occur in a specific case, you'll need to look at the assembly output, and trace it through very carefully. But it is not that "iOS 13 permits 11." It's that the specific situation **happens** to crash at 12.